# error with R CMD check because of package dependency

Tags: r, compilation, package

### Background

I am creating a **newpackage** that depends on **oldpackage**, and have indicated this dependency in the file `newpackage/DESCRIPTION`.

Furthermore,

- **oldpackage** is installed in the directory, `~/lib/R`
- my `.Rprofile` includes `.libPaths("~/lib/R")`

  - hence, I can successfully load **oldpackage** without specifying the library location, e.g., using the command `library(oldpackage)` in R

Despite the ability to load the package without having its library specified, `R CMD check newpackage` gives an error indicating that it can not fine **oldpackage**:

```
checking whether the package can be loaded ... ERROR 
Loading required package: oldpackage
Error: package 'oldpackage' could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc) :
  there is no package called 'oldpackage'
Execution halted


It looks like this package has a loading problem: see the messages for
    details.
```

### Questions:

1. Why is R unable to find the package?
2. Can I specify the library location in the DESCRIPTION file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding question 1), it is both a FAQ and yet somewhat annoying. `R CMD check` runs in vanilla mode, so it will not find user-level libraries.  As I recall, setting R_LIBS="...." in the call helps, so try that.

Regarding question 2), no you cannot give a location in DESCRIPTION.  Which makes sense as that file needs to work 'everywhere' whereas your location info is local to your machine.

Comment: Re 1) Yes, this is annoying and setting the `R_LIBS` environmental variable is an (the?) answer. I have `R_LIBS=$HOME/R/libs` and `export R_LIBS` (on consecutive lines) in my `.bashrc` in my `/home/username` to take care of this rather than remembering on a per-call basis.

Comment: @Gavin that solution has the desired effect. Given Dirk's answer, this is exactly the solution that I was looking for.