# Error in R CMD Check: Packages required but not available

Tags: r, packaging

I am trying to create a package. It depends on several packages. I added the imports to the namespace file and the Depends in the description file.

I found possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146348/r-package-dependencies) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432968/error-with-r-cmd-check-because-of-package-dependency), but these didn't work- I think because I am on CentOS.

This is what I see on my screen:

```
[hadoop@localhost RProjects]$ sudo R CMD check TextPreProcess
* using log directory ‘/home/hadoop/RProjects/TextPreProcess.Rcheck’
* using R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
* using platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
* using session charset: UTF-8
* checking for file ‘TextPreProcess/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package ‘TextPreProcess’ version ‘1.0’
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Packages required but not available:
  ‘RWeka’ ‘Snowball’ ‘lsa’ ‘plyr’ ‘snowfall’ ‘tau’ ‘tm’

See the information on DESCRIPTION files in the chapter ‘Creating R
packages’ of the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual.
```

I went through Writing R Extentions but I couldn't derive a lot of insight as to how to solve my problem.

Comment: My guess: `R CMD check` checks your package in a vanilla environment. This means it looks for your packages in a folder that is quite possibly different from your usual library folder. To rectify this, you may have to create a `.REnviron` file that points to your library folder. See the help here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Checking-and-building-packages

Comment: So would that be create a file->name it .Renviron->put R_LIB=<part> and put it in the folder, right?

Comment: Yes, but it's `R_LIBS=...` - note the plural. And you need to put in the correct folder, i.e. `~/.R/.Renviron` according to the manual, but you may have to experiment a little bit.

Comment: I did a .libPaths() in my console. It is showing the path where all the packages are installed, so, my guess is that is not the problem.

Comment: BTW I don't have a ~/.R directory

Comment: You can't check this from the console. The only way to check this is to run a script in `--vanilla` mode and return the lib path.

Comment: I'm assuming you have those packages installed? If so, the easiest way to recreate your libpaths when running `R CMD check` is to use `devtools::check("path/to/package")` which will set it up for you correctly.

Comment: Also, why are you running R with sudo? That shouldn't be necessary, and definitely isn't desirable.

Comment: @Andrie I have no clue about that. I'll have to google.
hadley I guess it's just comfort- now why is RStudio not desirable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working now.

What I did was:

1. add `~/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/2.15` to .libPaths (That's where my R library was)
2. Detach all libraries in R
3. Restart the R session. (For multiple sessions, close all of them.)
4. install the required packages.
5. Check if the Imports & Exports are correct in the namespace file.
6. Check if the required fields are available in the Description file. Make sure all dependencies are handled between 'Depends', 'Imports', 'Suggests' and 'Enhances'.
7. Checked it. `R CMD check <pkg>`. Built it. `R CMD build <pkg>`. Installed it. `R CMD INSTALL <tarball>`.
8. Done.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem because **packages were installed but for different R versions**.

To solve, I opened the old R version (the one the package was built under), and installed the missing packages under that version and it solved the problem.

E.g.

```
# Version should match the version your package was built in
R.version
# 3.5.1

install.packages(c('stringr', 'lubridate', 'testthat'))
```

#### Tips

- If you need to check your R version, simply type `R.version`
- If you need to switch R version, hold control while starting RStudio on windows, or on mac download a very simple application called [RSwitch](https://rud.is/rswitch/) to instantly switch between version (you'll still need to restart the R session with `.rs.restartR()`